# How can I remove the Null representation from PostgreSQL table when exporting to a text delimited file using pgAdmin4?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4, export-to-text

Im using Postgresql with pgadmin4 for exporting a table to a text-delimited file. I'm using 'Import/Export Data' and I need to change the default Null representation (\N) by an empty value.  But I can not find how.

I've tried ESCAPE key '''' but nothing seems to work. I need to keep it simple so I not using \copy.

```
id name age
1  john 20
2  mary 
3       34
```

When exporting to a text-delimited file
I get this
results

```
1~john~20
2~mary~\N
3~\N~34
```

I want to remove the null representation from the output
results expected

```
1~john~20
2~mary~
3~~34
```

Comment: `COPY tablename TO 'filename' WITH (FORMAT csv, DELIMITER '~', NULL '');`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with pgAdmin4 by the import/export, as it interprets the empty string as meaning that the NULL setting is omitted altogether, meaning it remains as its default of \N.  There is no problem with setting it to the empty string when using psql directly.  You could argue that this is a bug in pgAdmin4.

You might be able to get what you want by changing from the "text" format to the "csv" format, but that might cause other aspect to be messed up.

> I need to keep it simple so I not using \copy

I like to keep to simple as well, which is why I generally *do* use \copy and generally do *not* use pgAdmin4.

Comment: Hi jjanes;
Are you completely sure that there isn't a config file, that allows me to specify <empty> instead of \N. Or a empty representation for Null that I can Include on 'Null Strings' option. One thing I've learned from IT is that in 90% of cases, there is always a way to solve the equation.  I resist believing that the problem is in the 10% segment.